# Linking a fixed spreadsheet and a moving spreadsheet by cell value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I work for a small business that depends quite a lot on the weather. I’m trying to create a spreadsheet (in google sheets) to predict daily revenue. At the moment the spreadsheet simply multiplies last year’s corresponding day by the growth percentage to get this year’s daily values. I’m trying to include the weather forecast (15 days) in the calculation. I’ve managed to import the forecast successfully using an api tutorial that I found online (https://www.visualcrossing.com/weather-data), and include the forecast values in the revenue calculation.

Now for the issue:

*the revenue prediction is a spreadsheet with every row being a day of the year, making the spreadsheet 365 rows long
*the imported forecast (in another tab, not sure that’s relevant) is only 15 rows long and updates every day, meaning that it remains that length. No new row is added during the update: the data just shift one row up and the first day disappears while a new day takes the bottom row.

My formula in the revenue tab identifies the weather data in the weather tab by row but when I pull the formula down for the whole year (down 365 rows, that is), only the first 15 rows refer to existing data in the weather tab. -> Not only are the results obtained based on the wrong row as soon as the weather tab updates on day 2, but they are also referring to totally empty cells from day 16 on.

So my questions are:

*is there a way to force the daily weather forecast to remain on its row and add a new row every day, or failing that,

*is there a way for the formula to recognize the matching day cells and use the value of the cell x columns to the right of it, effectively skipping the row referencing altogether

I’ve added a [very simplified sketch of the spreadsheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YyNG.png) for the more visual helpers out here

Apologies if this is unclear, I do not have a tech background but am happy to clarify anything if needed.

-- Edit: Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bh1PE.png) of the revenue tab. The expected output is in column K. The values in it at the moment are incorrect.

Comment: Please kindly provide a sheet with sample data of expected output.

Comment: So are you just looking for a way to lookup the same date but prior year in a column and then match the prior weather values?

Comment: So say we have tab A (revenue) and tab B (weather). I want to find the corresponding dates of the same year in both tabs. Then in the cell that is n cells to the right of the tab A date I want to use a formula. That formula will contain values from tab B, and those values are found n cells to the right of the corresponding date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you just need a dynamic way to match the dates? I can't tell if you meant to have prior year data in other tab, but [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13sgEepF4dT1usDF6asua2ksNcWFCu9u3ASYBvJEsQ0w/edit#gid=0) matches your example and returns the value irrespective of the row order.

The formula being used (in the top row) is:

```
=B1*index(WeatherTab!B:B,match(A1,WeatherTab!A:A,))*index(WeatherTab!C:C,match(A1,WeatherTab!A:A,))
```